# Visual Studio runs project in 'Release' mode but not 'Debug' mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash, vshost.exe, vshost32

I am at a complete loss as to what is going on. This issue came out of nowhere. I checked the output window, which gave me this bit of information:

> MyApplication.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -1073740771 (0xc000041d)

Looks like vshost32.exe is having issues. I've reinstalled VS2010 and no luck.

Anyone have some clues? I'll update my question as I find more information. Many thanks to all who help in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It just happened to me too, in the middle of the work. I don't know the cause, but running Visual Studio as Administrator helped. If I run it such then that problem doesn't appear.